# Get the content of a tl variable

Tags: expl3, latex3

To get the content in a `tl` variable (in function `\foo_my_func:n`), I have several ways:

```
% 1
\foo_my_func:n { \l__foo_test_tl }
% 2
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \foo_my_func:n { N }
\foo_my_func:N \l__foo_test_tl
% 2
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \foo_my_func:n { V }
\foo_my_func:V \l__foo_test_tl
```

It seems they all give the same result in this simple case. But is there any difference?

Comment: What's your use-case? Maybe that would make your question clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to note is that `n` and `N` are both 'base' argument types. For `tl`, we use these two to distinguish

```
\tl_foo:n { tokens }
\tl_foo:N \l_tokens_tl
```

The `V` variant relates to `n`, so

```
\tl_foo:V \l_tokens_tl
```

is equivalent to

```
\tl_foo:n { <content of \l_tokens_tl> }
```

Depending on the internals of a particular function, it *may* be the case that you can pass a `tl` variable (`N`-type) and get the same behaviour as you see for the tokens themselves. However, this is not guaranteed and *should not be relied on*. It will depend on what action the function takes. For example, if we look at `\tl_to_str:n`, the results of

```
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { Hello }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_to_str:n { V }
\tl_to_str:n { \l_tmpa_tl }
\tl_to_str:V \l_tmpa_tl
```

are very different.

In general, you should *not* pass `tl` variables 'inside' an `n`-type argument. Either use a dedicated `N`-type function, if available, or pass the value using a `V`-type variant.

---

To be clear, the `N` type argument means 'exactly one token'. The most obvious place this is important is where we are then going to set (or adjust) the content of a `tl`. For example, `\tl_set:Nn` has to have the name of a token list variable as the first argument: it cannot be a `V` type. You *cannot* assume that an `N`-type argument 'turns into' some list of tokens inside the function using it.

In contrast, the `V`-type argument is *just* a way of getting to an `n`-type underlying value. Thus *anything* that will give a 'value' can be used here:

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set:Nn { NV }
\tl_set:NV \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpa_int
```

Notice that the fact I've got the value from an `int` here is *entirely irrelevant*: once the `V`-type has acted, I am left with a list of tokens which can be saved in a `tl`.

Comment: Could you explain the differnce between `N` and `V`? Or give some examples?

Comment: Recently, I've noticed that for `\int_eval:n`, `l3interface` says that any tl variable will be expand inside. So  `\int_eval:n { \l_my_tl }` may be OK here?